# Proof question using Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ have derivatives of all orders. Suppose that
>   $a<b$ and that $f(a) = f(b) = f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$.
>
> Prove that $f'''(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$

---

$f(a) = f(b)$ and since f is continuous and differentiable, we can use Rolle's Theorem.

$\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

So surely, differentiating twice more, $f'''(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$?

Or am I misunderstanding something? Why would the question ask for $f'''$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you'll have $f'(a), f'(b)$ and $f'(c)$ all zero (with $a<c<b$). What can you say about $f''$ on $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$? *Then* what can you say about $f'''$ between two points of interest...

Comment: You are using the fact that if $f'(x_0) = 0$ then $f^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$ for $n > 1$. Are you sure this is actually true? Try to prove or disprove this fact.